# What's the intuition behind a recurrent state $x$ being null recurrent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, expected-value

I am currently trying to come to grips with Markov Chains. I am confused by the nature of having a null recurrent state, which by definition is also recurrent. Say we have a Markov Chain starting at some $y\in E$  with a finite state space $E$. We know that $x$ is recurrent if and only if:

$P^{y}(\tau_{x} < \infty)=1$ where $\tau_{x}:=\inf\{n \in \mathbb N:X_{n}=x\}$ can be seen as the entry time of the Markov Chain into state $x$.

and thus $X_{n}=x$ for infinitely many $n \in \mathbb N$ and therefore the expected value of these visits to state $x$, i.e. $\mathbb E^{y}[\sum_{n \geq 0}1_{\{X_{n}=x\}}]=\infty$

Then, by definiton, this same recurrent state $x$ can be considered null recurrent if the expected mean recurrence time is infinite, i.e. $\mathbb E^{x}[\tau_{x}]=\infty$.

This seems extremely counterintuitive: null recurrence basically explains that the expected mean recurrence time to state $x$ of the Markov Chain is infinite. But since $x$ is recurrent, $X_{n}=x$ for infinitely many $n$ and $\tau_{x} < \infty$ almost surely.

In other words,

If a random variable $X$ is finite then how can its expectation $\mathbb E [X]$ be infinite?

Any explanations, and intuitions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Apologies if I'm guessing wrong here, but it _seems_ you're troubled by the possibility that some r.v. $R$ can be both (1) $P(R < \infty) = 1$ and yet (2) $E[R] = \infty$.  In your MC context, $R$ is $\tau_x$, but my guess is that it isn't any aspect of MC that's troubling you.  However, (1) and (2) together should not be troubling at all -- there are lots of r.v. on $\mathbb{N}$ with infinite expectation.

Comment: @antkam Yes, that is my actual question. It seems unintuitive that a finite r.v. $X$ can still have an infinite expectation $\mathbb E [X]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, there is no way for a recurrent state in a *finite*-state Markov chain to be null recurrent.  It is possible in an infinite-state Markov chain; for example, in the simple $50$-$50$ random walk on the integers, all the states are null recurrent.  (This was in saulspatz's original answer, but it was edited out.)

As to the general question of how a random variable can take on values that are finite, and yet have infinite expectation: That is indeed counter-intuitive, and yet there are undeniably examples of such random variables.  One such is involved in the [St Petersburg paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox).  None of the potential rewards is infinite, but the expected value is.

Here's another example: Let $X$ be a discrete random variable on $\mathbb{N}$, such that

$$
P(X = k) = \frac{6}{\pi^2k^2} \qquad k \geq 1
$$

This is a probability distribution, by the [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), but the expectation is

\begin{align}
E(X) & = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X = k) \\
     & = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k \\
     & = \infty
\end{align}

Strange but true!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is impossible to have a null-recurrent state in a finite-state Markov chain.  Given a finite-state Markov chain $C$ with a recurrent state $s$, consider the chain $C'$ obtained by making $s$ absorbing.  That is, the process stops once we get to $s$.  Now there is a specific [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain#Expected_number_of_steps) for the expected time to absorption in a finite-state absorbing Markov chain, which gives a finite value.  Thus, $C$ cannot have been null-recurrent.

Comment: Nice example.  The OP said "finite state space $E$" -- can this happen in a finite state space?  I'd imagine not but cannot think of a quick proof.

Comment: @antkam I overlooked that, thanks.  My intuition is the same as yours; I'll have to think about a proof, though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @BrianTung is great, so I just wanna supplement with some observations, bringing it back to Markov Chains.  Let $\tau_{xx}$ be the time, starting from state $x$, to revisit state $x$.  If no revisit ever occurs, we *define* (for that same point) $\tau_{xx} = \infty$.

So informally, $\tau_{xx}$ takes values in $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$.  Then we can think of the difference between transient and recurrent as simply:

- For transient state, $P(\tau_{xx} = \infty) > 0$ or in other words, $P(\tau_{xx} < \infty) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\tau_{xx} = n) < 1$.
- For recurrent state, $P(\tau_{xx} = \infty) = 0$ or in other words, $P(\tau_{xx} < \infty) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\tau_{xx} = n) = 1$.

  - Note that (for some MCs) even for recurrent state, $\tau_{xx} = \infty$ is possible, i.e. it is a non-empty event.  We're simply saying its prob is $0$.  (This is akin to "flipping all heads" in an infinite sequence of fair independent coin flips.  It is a non-empty event, i.e. possible, but with prob $0$.)

So a recurrent state simply means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(\tau_{xx} = n) = 1.$  This of course places very little restriction on the expected value $E[\tau_{xx}] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \color{red}{n \times} P(\tau_{xx} = n)$, and it should be no surprise the latter summation may diverge even if the former summation sums to $1$.

---

I think this surprises you (and many others, especially in the form of the St Petersburg Paradox) because people *expect* (ha!) the "expected" value to be some kind of "typical" value, when in fact it is just a certain summation and can be **completely overwhelmed by the tail.**

The St Petersburg Paradox has infinity in it, and may seem like a math curiosity, but it is not.  E.g. imagine you modify it a bit (e.g. with a tiny bit of depreciation, or a huge but limited bankroll), so the infinite gets shrunk to some merely huge-but-finite number, say expected payoff = \$1 billion.  Now it is no longer a "math paradox", but frankly it is no less of a surprise! I mean, who would pay \$1 billion to play that game?!?  The "expected value" of \$1 billion matches nobody's intuitive idea of what the word "expected" should mean.